# Positioning inside Header (CSS)

Tags: html, css, header, positioning

I'm trying to develop a page on my site and I'm not sure how to position the elements in my header correctly. I would like the logo to be in the center, and the sign up button to be at the same vertical position, but at the right of the page. Right now it looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/6ecvl2

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ovjkxgrc/

```
<body>
<header>
  <a href="" id="logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150">
  </a>

  <form action="pages/login.html" class="login_form"><input type="submit" class="login" value="Login or Sign Up"></form>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/levels.html">Levels</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/contents.html">Contents</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/arcade.html">Arcade</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/raffles.html">Raffles</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/store.html"></a></li>  
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

The CSS code is at the jsfiddle link I provided (the code is pretty long). Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa9jk9vm/)

I add a min-width to header, and float:right to login form...

```
/***************
BUTTON STYLES
***************/

* {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
}

.login {
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4bc970;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #3ac162;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*******************
GENERAL
*******************/

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


h3 {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

/*******************
HEADING
*******************/

header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 960px;
}

form {
  margin: 10px 
  width: 250px; 
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

logo {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/*******************
NAVIGATION
*******************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;

}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

/*******************
FOOTER
*******************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
}

/*******************
COLORS
*******************/

/* site body */
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

/* green header */
header {
  background: #b2d1f5;
  border-color: #92bced;
}

/* nav background on mobile */
nav {
  background: #92bced;
}

/* logo text */
h1, h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: #6ab47b; 
}

/* nav link */
nav a, nav a:visited {
 color: #fff; 
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color: #32673f;
}
```